# ns-landscape does not work when I change my phone orientation to landscape mode

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to change my font-size based on the orientation of the phone. Following this documentation: [Documentation](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling#root-views-css-classes)

Following is the code in my css file.

```
.item-title-heading {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
}

.ns-landscape .item-title-heading{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

In my HTML file I just, call the class like this:

```
<Label class="item-title-heading" text="Title Heading"></Label>
```

The issue that my code is always using `.ns-landscape item-title-heading` class and not using the `item-title-heading` ever.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any kind of information would be helpful!
Thanks in advance :)